# travis CI did not work with C compiler on GitHub?

Tags: c, gcc, github, travis-ci

travis CI did not work with C compiler.

.travis.yml :

```
sudo: required

language: c
 os:
   - linux

compiler:
   - gcc
```

GitHib repo link:
[Algorithms](https://github.com/piyush-maurya/algorithms)

travis CI error:

```
travis_time:end:0dcb3648:start=1438359476527442359,finish=1438359476614557866,duration=87115507
[0K$ cd piyush-maurya/algorithms
$ git checkout -qf 37da548d8f6e1ced6df4b3e22e2b5afd5435c2a2
travis_fold:end:git.checkout
[0K$ export CC=gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

travis_time:start:2b2b89e2
[0K$ ./configure && make && make test
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./configure: No such file or directory
travis_time:end:2b2b89e2:start=1438359476633265005,finish=1438359476641026855,duration=7761850
[0K
[31;1mThe command "./configure && make && make test" exited with 127.[0m

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

error links:
[travis CI error log](https://travis-ci.org/piyush-maurya/algorithms/builds/73582880)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't [specified how to build the project](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step).  For a C project, the default is the standard autotools-style `./configure && make`, but your project doesn't have a configure script (or a Makefile).

You can just add something like

```
build: cc file1.c file2.c …
```

To call the C compiler directly, but if you want the project to be useful to other people you should provide a Makefile (or use a build system like autotools, CMake, waf, etc.), then just do

```
build: make
```